# How to change to increase xml size by spyne?

Tags: python, spyne

I use `spyne` for my `SOAP` project. It works perfectly. But if I want to receive big files I see this error from `spyne`:

```
internal error: Huge input lookup
```

This error comes from `lxml` library. To fix it I have to change `huge_tree` property in `XmlDocument` class constructor. But I can't understand how can I do it by `spyne` which uses that `lxml` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `huge_tree=True` to the XmlDocument (or Soap11) constructor.